# Broken 5/16 x 2 1/2 lag screw in beam

Tags: bolts

I was trying to hang a weight storage unit in my garage and the lag screw snapped, leaving 1/8 of an inch of the screw exposed from the wall.

I'm not sure if I should use an extractor tool or another method to remove it.

I tried pliers and the screw didn't budge.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Rob

Comment: Do you need to use that spot for a fastener or can you just grind it flush and mount your thing a few inches over?

Comment: I would probably just use a big hammer and hammer it in(just because a hammer was handy), or use a grinder and grind it flat.

Comment: Did you drill pilot holes for the lag screws?  Maybe a large pair of vice grips.

Comment: @crip659: try doing that (using a hammer) and report back to us how well it works.

Comment: @whatsisname   !0 pound sledge(mistake hammer) works as well as any screwdriver/bolt driver.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention how deeply the screw is embedded -- only that it broke with 1/8" of screw exposed. I'll presume that most or all of the screw is buried in there. It's going to be tough to remove. It'll take almost as much force as what it took to break the screw.

If you can grind the screw flush to the wood and abandon it there, that's probably your easiest route.

If you really want it out, grind it to have a flat face on the end of the screw and then drill it with a left-hand drill bit. This is a drill that drills in the reverse or "unscrewing" direction. You may find that the torque of the drill is enough to back the screw out of the beam, but if not, you'll end up with a hole in which an extractor can be used.